# Efficiently storing uniform enum variant in collection

Tags: rust, types, storage

I am writing a library that parses an existing serialization format which has objects of various types and collections which can contain many of a uniform type (array, set, map).

My value type is defined as:

```rust
enum Value {
   Bool(bool),
   Int(i32),
   Float(f32),
   Str(String),
   // .. 20+ additional types
}
```

I can of course define my array type as `Vec<Value>` but this does not enforce each value in the array is of the same variant. For arrays I can get away with defining an array enum which contains a vec variant for each in the base value:

```rust
enum ValueArray {
   Bool(Vec<bool>),
   Int(Vec<i32>),
   Float(Vec<f32>),
   Str(Vec<String>),
   // etc.
}
```

This breaks down for a map type that stores a mapping of a type to another type as I have to define a variant for N*N types:

```rust
enum ValueMap {
   BoolBool(Map<bool, bool>),
   BoolInt(Map<bool, i32>),
   BoolFloat(Map<bool, f32>),
   BoolStr(Map<bool, String>),
   IntBool(Map<i32, bool>),
   IntInt(Map<i32, i32>),
   IntFloat(Map<i32, f32>),
   IntStr(Map<i32, String>),
   FloatBool(Map<f32, bool>),
   FloatInt(Map<f32, i32>),
   FloatFloat(Map<f32, f32>),
   FloatStr(Map<f32, String>),
   StrBool(Map<String, bool>),
   StrInt(Map<String, i32>),
   StrFloat(Map<String, f32>),
   StrStr(Map<String, String>),
   // etc.
}
```

Is there an alternative method that would:

- enforce uniform types contained in a collection
- store the enum variant once as opposed to for element in the collection

Comment: Are you sure you aren't reimplementing [`serde`](https://serde.rs/)?

Comment: Seems like `ValueArray` and `ValueMap` should be generic over the element and key/value types, rather than enums.

Comment: If you're okay with unsafe, this is possible by using `union`. Otherwise, you may want to consider using a declarative macro to shorten the amount of repetition.

Comment: This may also be possible without unsafe using dynamic dispatch, but both that and `union` will not be easy to implement.